# Adicionar evento onclick em botão por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

Estou tentando fazer uma página que, ao ser carregada, crie um botão que ao ser pressionado ele chame a função para volta no histórico:

```
function goBack(){
window.history.back();
}
function criarBotao(){
    var botao = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    botao.innerHTML = "Voltar";
    document.body.appendChild(botao);
    botao.onclick = goBack();
}
window.onload = criarBotao();
```

O Problema é que, toda vez que a página é aberta, a função goBack() acontece automaticamente, sem apertar o botão. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Deveria ser `botao.onclick = goBack;` sem parênteses. Escrever o nome da função com parênteses irá invoca-la, você não quer invoca-la, você quer apenas passa-la para o evento. O mesmo vale para `criarBotao`, deveria ser `window.onload = criarBotao;`

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que no momento que você foi adicionar a função `goBack` ao `botao`, foi feito de maneira errada, não se pode usar parenteses `()` após a função como você fez `botao.onclick = goBack();`, se não a função será invocada.

O certo então seria sem parenteses, como na parte mais abaixo `window.onload = criarBotao();`, onde o mesmo erro foi cometido.

Logo, o seu código ficaria dessa forma:

```
function goBack(){
    window.history.back();
}
function criarBotao(){
    var botao = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    botao.innerHTML = "Voltar";
    document.body.appendChild(botao);
    botao.onclick = goBack;
}
window.onload = criarBotao;
```